# How to configure default database in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drupal

In my computer i have  PostgreSQL, using this command i have checked its running `systemctl status postgresql` and i have install MySQL. now i'm stopping PostgreSQL using this `systemctl stop postgresq`   while i'm trying to install Drupal 8 with MySQL `Database type` is taking  `PostgreSQL` as default i have stop PostgreSQL still its selecting `postgres` as database type i want to install with `MySQL`. I don't want to uninstall `PostgreSQL` Thanks.

Comment: did  you try sudo service postgresql stop?

Comment: yes my PostgreSQL is stop i'm trying to install mysql pdo `sudo apt-get install php*-mysql` where ` * is version` like this type of command i have use to install but i can't get success

Comment: do you have an error message?